# operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'method' type

Tags: c#

I am trying to multiply textboxes declared in form2 here in form3. on form2 i have

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static string SetvalueforTextBox1;
    public static string SetvalueforTextBox2;
}
```

and also

```
public void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetvalueforTextBox1 = TextBox1.Text;
    SetvalueforTextBox2 = TextBox2.Text;
}
```

now on my form3 i want to display the multiplication of the values user input on form2

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) 
        * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1).ToString();
}
```

and i get error that "operator'*' cannot be applied for operands of type 'double and 'method' type

please help me

Comment: Seems forgotten to enclose `double.Parse` methods in parentheses: `label1.Text = (double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1)).ToString();`

Comment: `ToString()` converts an object to a string.  You can't multiply strings.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks a million it worked perfect. solved but i got another issue, i want the answer to be displayed as soon as the form opens. currently it only displays when i have the label clicked. thanks

Comment: Can you add another question for that? The form loading problem seems different from this one (add winforms tag for your convenience).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1).ToString()
```

First you parse string and ten again convert to string. Remove `.ToString()`

I think you want write:

```
label1.Text = (double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1)).ToString();
```

In first case you try multiply double and string in second case you cast multiplication result to string.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
label1.Text = double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1).ToString();
```

you are doing the following (let's break it down):

1. you parse a double from SetvalueforTextBox1
2. you parse a double from SetvalueforTextBox1
3. you call `ToString()` on your result of 2.
4. you try to multiply the result of the first parse with the string you got from the second part

This gives you the error.

What you need to do is encapsulate the multiplication and get the result als string, like so:

```
label1.Text = (double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1)).ToString();
```

This way, the result of the multiplication will be returned as string and assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're forgot to enclose `double.Parse` methods by parentheses before using `ToString`:

```
label1.Text = (double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1) * double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1)).ToString();
```

This is a right assignment order since both `double.Parse` evaluates first, then multiplying them & `ToString` method converts `double` value to a string required by `label1.Text` property.

Note that the operator precedence determines execution flow:

1. `double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1)` converts `string` value to a `double` for first operand.
2. `double.Parse(Form2.SetvalueforTextBox1).ToString()` converts string to double, then `ToString` reverts its value to a string as second operand.
3. Operator `*` tries to multiply `double` & `string` values, which is invalid in this context (operands must be having same data type to perform multiplication).